# Wrap many rails attributes with custom functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a number of models that have attributes on them that I need to apply some new behavior to when they are read. I'm fairly new to Ruby/Rails so right now I'm just defining a getter for a property and applying my functionality on top of it (similar to something like profanity filtering), but I'm going to be doing this for a **lot** of objects/properties and would like something cleaner.

For example, this is how I'm accomplishing it now, for a `Post` object's `body` attribute:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Replaceable

    #...

    # A key point is that we want to keep the original content in the db
    def body
        profanity_filter(self[:body])
    end
end
```

... and my concern looks like this:

```
module Replaceable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def profanity_filter(content)
        # filter and update content...

        content
    end
end
```

This works and I'm happy with it, except that now I have to apply it to many fields across the app, and I'd like something a bit more elegant than overriding getters everywhere.

I looked into delegates so that I could do something like

```
delegate :body, :title, :etc, :to => :profanity_filter
```

... but that doesn't work because I can't pass the content that needs to be filtered.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect time to implement your own class macro.

I'll reuse your `Replaceable` module do define this macro.

First, let's see what the macro look like.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Replaceable

  profanity_attrs :body, :foo, :bar, ...
end
```

Then we implement it

```
module Replaceable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def profanity_filter(content)
    # filter and update content...

    content
  end

  # This module will be `extend`ed by the model classes
  module Macro
    def profanity_attrs(attributes)
      # Note the implicit `self` here refer to the model class
      attributes.each do |attr|
        class_eval do
          define_method(attr) do
            # Note the `self` here refer to the model instance
            profanity_filter(self[attr])
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  included do
    extend Macro
  end
end
```

P.S. I don't really know what `profanity` means, so feel free to change the name of the macro :)

Comment: Oh, this is gorgeous! Thanks so much Aetherus. For context, a profanity is a swear word, so the functionality here is to replace profanities with "****" or something like that (I'm actually doing something a bit different from that, but the mechanics are the same).