# Rails is persisting on validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have an ActiveRecord model that does find and replace filtering on an attribute when its accessor is called, and I'm doing it like the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130198/wrap-many-rails-attributes-with-custom-functionality). It looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Replaceable

    profanity_attrs :body, :title
end
```

If you haven't looked at the link, then there's a macro called profanity_attrs that calls a profanity_filter method that does find/replace on known keywords.

So when I have something like `body = "Oh my poop"` and I do a replace with **** so that the filter returns "Oh my ****" then that's what it looks like, and I'm very happy. The DB shows "Oh my poop" and the view shows "Oh my ****", which is exactly what I want, until... I add validation. So if I do this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Replaceable

    validates :body, length: { maximum: 255 }

    profanity_attrs :body, :title
end
```

Then it still does the replace properly, but the replaced value will be persisted (ie. the db contains "Oh my ****"), and that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It appears as if the validator is mutating the field that it validates.

Is there a way to preserve the validation, but not have it persist the value returned from the accessor?

Comment: My guess is the Rails validators use the basic accessors to fetch the data, then validate them, then put that back in to the object, and now your accessors are compromised. This is a fairly silly idea, but I'll throw it out there just in case you end up with nothing else: the accessor that your `profanity_attrs` macro redefines could look at the call stack, and if it sees a validation method, just return the normal data instead of cleaning it. Another option would be to try maybe a way of only cleaning the data for view code, maybe with helpers/decorators.

Comment: If you never want the profanity-sanitized attributes to end up in the DB, why don't you use a wrapper that filters when _showing_ the model?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you are not setting the attribute value in your **profanity_filter** implementation, that you are just returning a filtered copy of it (just validating an attribute shouldn't change it's value unless you're accidently also setting its value in your profanity_filter method).

In addition I would also change a little bit what you did in the macro you defined, instead of

```
define_method(attr)
```

I would define the method as

```
define_method("#{attr}_clean")
```

and in the views access the filtered version of the attribute by calling the "clean" version, i.e.

```
<%= post.body_clean %>
```

Comment: I'm not mutating the value. profanity_filter takes a `content` param, creates a copy ( `content_out = content` ) and then mutates and returns `content_out`. The reason for making the macro is because I don't want to rename all of the accessors and then have to update all of the clients as well (the models are returned in API calls).

Comment: From a small test I run with rails 5, it didn't seem like your approach actually changed the value that was saved to the DB (if truly you're not updating the value in your filter method).

Comment: I'm fairly new to ruby/rails so I'll take another look to be sure. If I remove the validates: :body length: {...} line, then it'll work as expected. Maybe there's a Concern that's doing something that I'm missing.

Comment: Be aware that Strings in Ruby are mutatable, I don't know how you're updating `content_out` but there's a chance you're affecting the original string.
the best way to test those things are in the rails console, run `rails c` and run it there
    `a = "hello"
    b = a
    b[/ll/] = "X"
    b  (prints "heXo")
    a  (prints "heXo")`